# How i can use cer with private key or ( PKCS#12 ) for connect with special server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, certificate, private-key, server-to-server

I have a certificate file(cer) sent in response to my request for a certificate and my private key . How can I use it for authentication and encryption for the connection. If I do not have , you can add to it. Sorry if this is a stupid question . I want to understand the principle . Language is not important , but if it is important I use ruby

Comment: Please clarify, what are you looking for - keeping ssl connection with a remote server or encrypt messages and pass a client authentication manually?

Comment: I try understand, how i can start encrypted connection with remote server using SSL

Comment: Am I right, you want a remote server authenticate the client? Are you going to use HTTP protocol or sockets?

Comment: I use HTTP, and i want authenticate using certificate

Answer (score 0):

If HTTPS is an option, you can get both server and client authentication.

There are a lot libraries for this just check [httpclient gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.1.5.2/HTTPClient):

```
# Configuring OpenSSL options. See HTTPClient::SSLConfig for more details.
user_cert_file = 'cert.pem'
user_key_file = 'privkey.pem'
clnt.ssl_config.set_client_cert_file(user_cert_file, user_key_file)
clnt.get_content(https_url)
```

and this topic [HTTP library for Ruby with HTTPS, SSL Client Certificate and Keep-Alive support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886501/http-library-for-ruby-with-https-ssl-client-certificate-and-keep-alive-support)